# How to select only number in txt file using command line functions in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a file that has this format:

```
<somecharacters> 1 <somecharacters>
<somecharacters> 2 <somecharacters>
<somecharacters> 4 <somecharacters>
<somecharacters> 9 <somecharacters>
```

I need to parse out the largest numeral. I tried using `FINDSTR` and `FIND`, but just don't have enough experience with the Windows command line...

Comment: It's trivial in something like Perl or Python. You really ought to use the tool for the job.

Comment: FIND and FINDSTR identify which lines contain a search string, but they are not useful for parsing out a substring. Can `<somecharacters>` contain spaces?

Comment: <somecharacters> can contain html code for example. Yeah, perl and python should do the job... i guess i'll have to do that.

Comment: So the answer is yes - there may be additional spaces. That complicates things. You need to be more specific as to what the format of each line is and what are the rules for identifying which numbers are to be parsed. After all, there could be additional numbers in `<somecharacters>` (unless you tell us otherwise). Even using perl, no one could provide a solution with confidence unless you provide more specific requirements.

Comment: sorry for note being specific: the line looks like this:
<li><a href="9.0.1.7433/"> 9.0.1.7433/</a></li>
so no numbers, only parsing out 7433 for example would sufice.
every line has this format, so comand could just repeat it untill the last line, and remembering the last number, it will olways be the largest, i just dont know hot to exclude html characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the lines in your file are really consistently formatted like that, then this should work (I used the attribute instead of the inner text)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set maxPort=0
for /f "tokens=6 delims=<./ " %%N in (test.txt) do (
  if %%N gtr !maxPort! set maxPort=%%N
)
echo maxPort=%maxPort%
```

But if you have additional lines that look different that should be ignored, you will want to use FINDSTR to filter out the lines you don't want to parse. The FINDSTR command would go inside the IN() clause. FINDSTR has limited support for regular expressions that probably meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks Alot! that is really cool.
In the mean time i managed to do it with a workaround,
used FINDSTR to filter out lines, thes used SED from linux, by isnstalling gnuwin32, to parse only numbers, and then used a simpler version of FOR, that actually takes one number after a number, stops at the last one, that is luckily the max, and yeah.
But thanks, i'll try your solution!